# Tangents lines passing through $(0,0)$ of $x=y^2-y+1$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, curves, tangent-line

What are the equations of the tangents lines passing through $(0,0)$ of $x=y^2-y+1$?
How do you get them?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax Tutorial !](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Also, what are your thoughts or potential attempts on this ?

Comment: Gee, I think I will go solve your problem for tangent lines going through $(1,1)$ - see ya all !!!

Comment: There is no tangent line passing through $(0,0)$ as your parabola does not go through the origin. If $x = y = 0$ then $0 = 0^2 - 0 + 1$ which implies $0 = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Consider a variable straight line through the origin: $y=tx$, and write the condition which ensures the quadratic equation in $x$ for the intersection points with the parabola has a double root.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $(a,b)$ be the point on the parabola.

Slope of line through $(a,b)$ and $(0,0):$

$m= \dfrac {b}{a} .$

Differentiate the equation:

$1= 2y\dfrac{dy}{dx} -\dfrac{dy}{dx}.$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{2y-1}.$

Equate: $m= \dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at $(a,b).$

$\dfrac{1}{2b-1}= \dfrac{b}{a}.$

Use $a = b^2 -b +1$ to  solve for $b$ in the above equation.

Can you take it from here?